Tableau Public Data type from number to Date not working
Why can't I change Year column from number to Date format in Tableau?
Change data type from number to date in Tableau public
Tableau Public Data type from number to Date not working
Tableau public is not allowing me to change Data type from Number to Date. It is not showing any Data type details pane at all.

I change the data type on canvas level and it changed the format on data source. SOLVED!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
